# How can I read a file (in any directory) which name(only file.txt) is passed as parameter? C++

Tags: c++, file, parameters, directory

I want to follow this schema:

```
    //Read filename
    string filename; 
cout << "ONLY Name of the file you want to read, not directory: "; 
cin >> filename;

    //Find file in disk C and open it
    ifstream ifs(.................);
    while( int cc = FileRead( ifs, buff ) ) {
       etc. (trivial)
    }
```

Comment: You want to make a program that searches the HD for a file with the parameter name and reads it?

Answer (score 3):

```
ifstream ifs(filename.c_str());
```

Could have googled for it really...

Comment: Thanks but I only want to enter the file name, not the directory.

Comment: @user2948426, edit your qustion to be specific. Nobody on SO is a mindreader.

Comment: I wrote "which name is passed as parameter" in the tittle, and after your first question I edited the cout's message writing "ONLY". I thought it was clear because people usually ask for read using C:\....file, but I said name.

Comment: @user2948426, good thing you edited it. because "filename" is not specific enough, since it can be relative or full. Regardless, without the directory name, where do you plan to look for the file?

Comment: I would like to look for the file in a predefined directory, outside the project directory. But I don't know if I could do it concatenating both of them, directory and filename in a string. The idea is that the user will only have to write the name and he wont take care/doesn't care about writing the file url. If you put files into other folder, you'll only change it in the code.

Comment: @user2948426 You should look into working with environment variables (google is your friend). It will allow you to set the directory up without having to change the code every time. That's what actual professional grade software does. After that consider checking. Also, take a look at Boost.Filesystem for working with paths.